# Enable Bitlocker on OS partition without extra repartitioning

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker

I have two partitions on my HDD:

- 300Mb EFI System Partition
- XXXGb NTFS Primary Partition (Boot) for
  the main OS (`C:`).

Now I want to enable Bitlocker on `C:`. but it wants to create an extra partition by shrinking my `C:`:

[image]

According to [this article](https://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/103486), two partitions should be enough. I also have a similar Bitlocker encrypted laptop with 2 partitions. I assume this extra partition is to load the bootloader which eventually has to hold the decryption mechanism for the `C:` to boot. So I have two questions:

1. Why can it not use the EFI System Partition?
2. Are there ways to allow/force Bitlocker use the EFI System Partition?

Comment: If you destroy the the EFI Partition the computer will not boot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that 300MB EFI is not enough to be used by Bitlocker. Once I extended the EFI drive to 1GB, Bitlocker didn't ask me to create a third partition, but simply used the existing EFI one.

I do not know how the minimal size requirement is computed.